# Why does my Anti-Virus think that my C++ program is a virus and how can I fix it?

Tags: c++, antivirus

When compiling and running my program, my antivirus (Kaspersky Security Cloud) automatically deletes the executable and tells me to restart my computer so that it can disinfect my computer. I have a few questions.

1. Why does the AV think my exe is a virus?
2. How can I stop it from thinking it's a virus?
3. How can I retrieve my executable?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Turn off your AV?

Comment: Just add your build folder as an exception in your AV.

Comment: Some AVs detect executable compilations as a malicious behaviour. In order to avoid detection, add your Debug/Release folders to your AV's exception list.

Comment: This is a well-known problem, a quick search should give you plenty of others that have the same problem. As mentioned, the two solutions is to either turn off the AV, or add your project directories to the AV's whitelist.

Comment: give us the code or at least something to work with. This way I can list you 100k things but IDK which one is going to help you.

Comment: Another solution is to get a better AV. Kaspersky, Norton and AVG are known to be very greedy. I've been using Eset NOD32 for a long time and have never had a problem with it.

Comment: I do love ESET as well!!!!!!! The answer below seems to be more about firewalls than AV. But I prefer fixing my code not to trip any AV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your anti-virus should put the executable into a quarantine where you can tell it whether or not the quarantined file is actually malicious. This video might help you with that: https://youtu.be/NA6HrN-gO5A.

As mentioned before, adding your build folder or project directory to the AV's exception list is also a solution.

An anti-virus can think a program is a virus for many reasons.

- Does the program open ports to send/receive data
- Does it requests things from the internet that could be seen as malware
- Are there any protocols that you're using that are insecure

Comment: That isn't close to what it's doing. What OP is experiencing is a heuristic analysis false-positive. What you are suggesting deals with firewalls after the software is already running. This is triggering AV software before the software ever runs.

Comment: @Andy are you saying the anti-virus software can't look into the functionality of an executable to determine if it is malicious or not? From what I understand, anti-virus can determine if an executable is malicious before it ever executes based on previously defined signatures or more advanced methods like code analysis. I might have a misunstanding of what they can do though?

Comment: @anthony no. I suggest make some program and compile it on one machine exe/msi file to machine next to you and it will fire AV up, at that point your function names and everything you had in your fancy code is dialed down to 0s and 1s. AVs mostly act on behavior of the program.

Comment: @CEPB I'm currently studying to get into security, so I might genuinely be misunderstanding what a host-based anti-virus is capable of or how signatures work. If a portion of complied code, 0s and 1z, is similar or matches a signature that has been previously identified as malware, would that not be quarantined? Or does the antivirus only compare the entire file to a signature as a whole instead of portions like I'm imagining?

Comment: It have been a while, since I studied security my self, but some AV might be using signature, but most of them are behavior based I believe. Try writing to Windows system folders (Windows/Windows64) just a single byte AVs would stop you.